# How to record video with sound emgu cv

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I have following code in ProcessFrame event:

```
frame = new Mat();
capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
if (isRecord && _writer.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)

{_writer.Write(frame);}
```

Output video doesn't have sound.

I want to record both video and  sound .

Comment: fixed English, tabbed unformatted code

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you cannot. There are no provisions within EmguCV/OpenCV that provide for manipulation or even capture of an audio track. EmguCV/OpenCV are SDKs for Computer Vision applications are not really intended to to do general purpose manipulation of video/audio streams.

In general I have found it is better to avoid EmguCV/OpenCV for video capture and use these tools strictly for computer vision applications. I can recommend MFormats by [Medialooks](http://medialooks.com) asa very good SDK for capture and manipulation of Video and Audio streams.

**Disclaimer, I do not work for Medialooks nor do I have any financial stake in the company. Just a satisfied customer.**

Doug